# STM32 Register Value Doesn't Change

Tags: stm32, cmsis

**Problem Definition**

**Board: STM32F407**

Hello all,

I am trying to change any register value. But it doesn't change. For example if we look GPIOB port's MODER register it has default "0x0000 0280" value for port B. This means that MODER registers 7 and 9 have a value of 1, other MODER registers have a value of 0. I am trying to change 1 to 0 for MODER 7 register. I am sharing the simple one-line I did below.

```
GPIOB ->MODER &= ~(1 << 7);
```

[DEBUG PROCESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNsIp.png)
[image]

I am debugging the code. And register value doesn't change. I tried for some another register to see whether it is done or not. Bu it didn't.
What can I do, what is my fault.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the GPIOB clock in one of the RCC regesters first.

If the clock is disabled the digital part of the peripheral is disabled too.

Comment: Actually, I tried the above code when the register value couldn't see the transition from 1 to 0 even though I enabled the clock in another project. Maybe I made a mistake while watching the recording value. Anyway thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. And the solution is you forgot to enable the clock of the peripheral.
RCC->AxBxENR |= (1<<BITPOSITION);